# backslash character in string literals

Tags: c++, c

Why is the output of the following program:

```
str                 str
```

and not this:

```
str str
```

This is the program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "str \
                str \n";
}
```

I tried both gcc 4.7.2 and MSVC-11.0.

Comment: Maybe OP wasn't sure if the issue was related to C or C++ syntax

Answer (score 10):

Because `\` before a newline denotes line-continuation.<sup>*</sup>  So your two lines are literally spliced together, including all the whitespace.

You could try this instead:

```
std::cout << "str "
                "str \n";
```

because adjacent string literals are concatenated.

---

<sub>* From C99, section 5.1.1.2:</sub>

> Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line
>   character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.

Comment: It escapes just the newline, not whitespace after it, to be precise.

Answer (score 4):

The backslash is replaced by the preprocessor, with the following rule: each sequence of `\` followed by new-line character is deleted.

> **C11 (n1570), § 5.1.1.2 Translation phases**
>   Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line
>   character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.

A common solution is to use adjacent string litterals concatenation.

```
std::cout << "str"
             "str\n";
```

> **C11 (n1570), § 5.1.1.2 Translation phases**
>   Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

Comment: Your answer implies that the same thing occurs with the actual character sequence `\n` rather than a newline character.  I know that's not what you meant, but it's potentially confusing!

Answer (score 3):

The backslash before the newline says the string is continued on the next line. There are many whitespace chars on the front of the next line.

Try:

```
std::cout << "str " 
                "str \n";
```

Comment: This does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: Although he's the only one who actually explained the problem of all the whitespace.

Comment: Oh yes. c++ is not java. Fixed for future generations by removing the + between the two strings. (And thank you.)

Comment: @CatPlusPlus What the operator + sees are pointers. Example, error from gcc: `error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’)` for `"a"+"b"`.

Comment: @Shahbaz Different rules for C and C++, I guess. They don't decay in C++ (`error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [4]’ and ‘const char [4]’ to binary ‘operator+’`). Did I mention I hate questions tagged both [tag:c] and [tag:c++].

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, right. It was the obvious thing for it to decay to pointers in C, and in C++ not.